# How can I correctly use the Canvas class to show an image into an ImageView in this simple Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-image

I am absolulty new in Android and I am doing some experiment with the **Canvas** object.

I am trying to add it to a **Canvas** and then show it into a retrieved **ImageView** (I know that this is not the standard and simplest way to show an image into an ImageView but this is only a simplified experiment for a further more complex thing that I have to do using **Canvas**).

So I have a **star.png** (a 32x32 px icon into my **/res/drawable/** folder) and I am trying to

This is my **activity_main.xml** layout configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout contain the **ImageView** having **id=star_container** that is where I have to draw the image using the **Canvas**

And this is the **MainActivity** class that handle this view:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star_container);

        Canvas canvas;

        Bitmap star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(32, 32, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(output);

        canvas.drawBitmap(star, star.getWidth() + 2, 0, null);

        imgView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), output));


    }
}
```

So into the **onCreate()** method I retrieve the **ImageView** where the image have to be placed. Then I create a **Bitmap** object retrieving the **star.png** image from the resoruces that will be added to the **otuput** Bitmap using the **Canvas**.

Finally I set this **output** Bitmap into the retrieve **ImageView**.

So I expected that, when the app is running, the previous **ImageView** contains the **star.png** image but it does not appear.

I have no error when I execute this app but the only output that I obtain is the textual message defined into the **TextView**.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I modify this code and let it work?

Comment: That's not how you use Canvas at all.  TO draw a view using a Canvas, you create a custom View class and override onDraw.  You'll be passed a Canvas to draw to.  THe code you have here is so convoluted as to be unsalvagable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documents:

> left: The position of the left side of the bitmap being drawn

The problem is here :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(star, star.getWidth() + 2, 0, null);
```

You're using a value for left that is out of bitmap bounds, So nothing is drawn, try this:  `canvas.drawBitmap(star, 0, 0, null);`

Android API provides another method to set `Bitmap` as `drawable` directly :
 `ImageView#setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)`

I think it's a better practice to implement a custom `View` and explore `Canvas` capabilities there (in `onDraw` method)

Answer (score 0):

another way - using rect area:

```
    Canvas canvas;

    Bitmap star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(star.getWidth(), star.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas  = new Canvas(output); 
    Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, star.getWidth(), star.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(star, null, source, null);    
    imgView.setImageBitmap(output);
```

Comment: No I can't because, as explained, this is the first step to understand how to use Canvas. Now I am trying with a single image but I need Canvas because I have to create an image composition